# Language switcher, redirect to current page with symfony2.0

Tags: redirect, symfony, routes

I set up a language switcher on my website but right now I only know how to redirect to the homepage:

```
public function englishAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->get('session')->setLocale('en_US');
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
}
```

How can I do to redirect to the current page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
```

Or another solution: you may put back url link as a get parameter and use it in redirect in your "englishAction" action.